# Sort Multidimensional Array Alphabetically not Working?

Tags: php, usort

So I have an array called $links

```
array(
    [0] = array(
        'type' => 'thread'
        'url' => 'blah blah blah'
    ),
    [1] = array(
        'type' => 'media'
        'url' => 'blah blah blah'
    ),
    [2] = array(
        'type' => 'website'
        'url' => 'blah blah blah'
    )
);
```

What I am trying to do is sort this array alphabetically using "type". For this I am using `usort()`

```
usort($links, create_function('$b, $a', 'return $a["type"] - $b["type"];'));
```

The problem is, this is not actually sorting the array... all it does is REVERSE the array. After running through, I get Website > Media > Thread. If I process it a second time, it reverses back to Thread > Media > Website.

The final result should be Media > Thread > Website. Am I missing something? Why is this not sorting correctly?

Comment: `echo "thread" - "media"` → `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, instead:

```
usort($links, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strcmp($a["type"], $b["type"]);'));
```

Comment: @JasonAxelrod the reason it wasn't working for you is that you were trying to subtract strings, which doesn't work in the same way as numbers would; `strcmp()` does this kind of comparison for strings instead :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  Every answer I've read  so far suggests using usort to order arrays within an array, but not one of them mentioned strcmp and I was tearing my hair out.  This answer and comment explained everything and made me feel stupid for not working it out sooner! :)